# Splitting string on certain word into ArrayList - java

Tags: java, string, split

I am stuck splitting a string into pieces to store the pieces into an ArrayList. I can split the string onto `" "`, but I'd like to split the string onto `"farmersmarket"` and store it into an `Arraylist`. To be able to return one of the indexed pieces of string.

```
    ArrayList<String> indexes = new ArrayList<String>();
    String s = file; 

    for(String substring: s.split(" ")){
        indexes.add(substring);
        }
    System.out.println(indexes.get(2));
```

Any ideas to split a string on `"farmersmarket"`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
String[] tokens = yourString.split("farmersmarket");
```

And afterwards you don't need an `Arraylist` to get a specific element of the tokens. You can access every token like this

```
String firstToken = tokens[0];
String secondToken = tokens[1];
```

If you need a `List` you can do

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(tokens);
```

and if it has to be an `Arraylist` do

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(tokens));
```

Comment: Can I do store them in an `ArrayList`? I need the `ArrayList` to do something more with the strings.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you still want to return a list of strings when the input string doesn't have the character on which you are splitting, Arrays.asList(inputString.split(" ")) should work.

E.g. Arrays.asList("farmersmarket".split(" ")) would return a list that contains only one element--farmersmarket.